# Wordpress: How to move 'select options'-/'add to cart'-button below product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

So, the 'select options'-/'add to cart'-button used to be below the product title. Now it's not anymore. I haven't done anything except updating plugins. I guess it can be fixed by CSS, but I don't know how.
Site: [Click](https://caskjaer.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

To get this layout:
[image]

Comment: Yes!! Perfect! Thanks so much George